# C# code to create AutoMapper DDL values (text,value) from *any* Domain Model Object, providing the two field names in the parameters

Tags: c#, service, repository-pattern, automapper

What would the C# code be to create a (service) method to return an object (ViewModel for DDL) using [AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com) and provide the two field names as parameters?

DDL is for a Drop Down List:

```
public class DDLitems {
    public string text {get;set;}
    public string value {get;set}
}
```

My horrible pseudo C# code idea: (yea no idea how to do this yet):

```
public IList<DDLobject> AutoMapDDLvalue( IList<object> source,
                                         type objectClass.textFieldName,
                                         type objectClass.valueFieldName)
{
    var EntityRepository = new EntityRepository();
    Mapper.CreateMap<source.type, DDLobject>()
          .ForMember(dest => dest.text, 
                      opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.objectClass.textFieldName))
          .ForMember(dest => dest.value, 
                      opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.objectClass.valueFieldName));
    return Mapper.Map<IList<source>, IList<DDLobject>>(EntityRepository.Get());
 }
```

I just thought that the field types would need to be converted to string.  I guess we could add a generic .ToString() to each.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have absolutely no experience with AutoMapper, but I guess the problem boils down to getting a property from an object, when you know the property name only at runtime.

If that is the question, that's what reflection is for :)

You can get a property out of an object using this:

```
public object GetProperty(object obj, string propertyName)
{
  PropertyInfo pi = obj.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName);
  object value = pi.GetValue(o, null);
  //or object value = pi.GetGetMethod().Invoke(obj, null)
  return value;
}
```

Comment: Yep.  This really has nothing to do with AutoMapper, other than to clarify the parameters needed.  Nice code.